# How to combine the sum of identical key:value pairs in Firestore Query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have firestore database setup with entries like this

```
Database/users/(userId)/cart/
  - dT3897G5H9398T5H
       quantity: 1
  - aG895T398HG509349
       quantity: 3
  - aG895T398HG509349
       quantity: 6
```

I'm trying to get the sum of the quantities... If I do this:

```
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(userId)
          .collection('cart')
          .getDocuments();
      if (snapshot == null) {
        return;
      }
      snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        var cartTotal;
        cartTotal = doc.data['quantity'];

        print(cartTotal);
```

I get...

```
I/flutter ( 5371): 1
I/flutter ( 5371): 3
I/flutter ( 5371): 6
```

I'm not sure how to combine the sum of those values though :(

Comment: Please avoid modifying your original question with new code. This prevent other readers understanding what is your exact problem. If you want to add some new code, please add it at the bottom of your question indicating what are the changes and maybe why you did them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your code along the following lines:

```
getCartTotal(String userId) async {

    var cartTotal = 0;

    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(userId)
        .collection('cart')
        .getDocuments();

    if (snapshot == null) {
      return;
    }

    snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
      cartTotal = cartTotal + doc.data['quantity'];
    });
    print(cartTotal);

  }
```

In your current code, for each document in the `QuerySnapshot`, you are:

1. Declaring the `cartTotal` variable
2. Assigning a value to `cartTotal`
3. Printing the value of `cartTotal`

---

Note that if you plan to have carts with a lot of documents (i.e. orders) you may use a different approach. For example, you could calculate the sum for each cart with a Cloud Function (each time there is a new document created in the cart), instead of querying all the documents of the cart each time you want to get the sum.

Comment: I've adpated the code of my answer. However, note that you don't need to do `if (doc == null) {return;}`, because "A QueryDocumentSnapshot contains data read from a document in your Firestore database as part of a query. The document is guaranteed to exist ...  query results contain only existing documents", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    return ref.collection('users').get().then(snapshot => {
        let total_count = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            total_count += Number(doc.data().quantity);
        });

        return total_count;
    });
```